# Click anywhere on page show fullscreen div

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I looking for the effect from the website below. If you click anywhere on a page a fullscreen div / background will be shown. The links links etc. still have to be clickable.

---

My website is: http://www.ee12.dk/ (password engbirk2012) , if you click the first time it works, but I want the layer to be shown again and again.

```
<div class='clickOnMe' onmouseup='mouseUp(this);' onmousedown='mouseDown(this);'>
</div>

<style>
    .clickOnMe { 
        margin-top: -50px; 
        min-height: 100%; 
        min-width: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 9999999999999999999999999;
    }
</style>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function mouseUp(element){
          element.style.background = 'none';
          element.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }

    function mouseDown(element){
        element.style.backgroundImage="url('http://www.ee12.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/blackani.gif')";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Bro you should start with formatting you're code first so it's more readable. It would increase you're change of good answers. I will do it later when I have time if you doesn't do it :)

Comment: *The links links ect. still have to be clickable* - **etc**?? That is not a clear problem description hence voting to close.

Comment: Usually I'm very good at guessing what people are actually asking in unclear questions, but this time I'm giving up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bind a click event to the body of the page and using jquery bind a click event to every A tag on the page using $('body').on("click", 'a', function(){})
Then in the click bound to the A tags, set a variable (DoIt=false). Then in the click event for the page, check the variable, and then show the div based on that variable.
Then be sure to always set it to true again at the end of the body's click event.

```
$('body').click(function(){ if (DoIt == true) {/* do something */} DoIt=true;});

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){ DoIt == false ;});
```

I think you get the idea. Coding from memory on an ipad here. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm not super strong at javascript or jquery at all. Can you try to explain it to a dummy ? :))

Comment: Sorry @JensKold, I was on an ipad when replying to the question.  Looks like the other response from "doforumda" will be closer to what you want.
My response would set a variable "DoIt" to false if you clicked on a link: an "a" tag.  From memory, if you register a click event on the body, and click on an element, "a" tag, it will fire the click on the link and then fire the click on the body.  So by using the variable, you can stop the click event code for the body from doing anything by checking the "DoIt" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/np7g9435/)

Below is the working code. This code is using `div` tag to be shown as fullscreen when you press the mouse button and will hide it when you release it. You can tweak it for your requirement.

```
$(document).mousedown(function () {
    $('.fullscreen').show();
}).mouseup(function () {
    $('.fullscreen').hide();
});
```